# Javascript Token Transformation

Tags: javascript, regex, token, replace

Looking to get a JS replacement function to change [[ ... ]] to myFunction('...').

```
"player.email = '[[UserID]]@email.com';"
```

to become:

```
"player.email = '" + myGetterFunction('userid') + "@email.com';"
```

[[ ]]  becomes  myFunction('')
and value inside [[]] becomes lowercase

**Assumptions**:

- Entire string will be wrapped in double quotes
- Only single quotes and escaped quotes will be inside
- The value "UserID" will always change, and can contain spaces and other non-alpaNumeric characters except for [[ and ]] pairs.

Can anyone point me in direction of a mostly-generic setup for this? The part stumping me is lowercasing the contents of [[]] without doing some crazy splitting. Figuring some Ninja Regex exists for token replacement already (samples I've seen so far are replacing with *specific* values for each token, I just want to transform the token and wrapper.

Comment: So, you're trying to lowercase the username, and everything after the `@`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a replacement function to process the captured groups:

```
str.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, function(text) {
    return myGetterFunction(text.toLowerCase());
});
```

`/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g` may look complex, but it's really just a bunch of escaped square brackets. `(.*?)` is a non-greedy capturing group.

Comment: Why is there anything besides just `return myGetterFunction(text.toLowerCase());` in the replacement function? What's with all the extra quotes and stuff?

Comment: Really close. Missing the removal of the [[ ]] afterwards. I modified as such (please update your answer, since I don't want to be all douchy and add and accept my own):  var _e = "\"email = '[[UserID]]@email.com';\"".replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, function(text) {
    return "\" + myGetterFunction('"+text.toLowerCase().replace(/((\[\[)|(\]\]))/gi,"") + "') + \"";
}); console.info(_e);